# Catching Exceptions In Swift?

Tags: swift

From what I understand, it is not possible to catch exceptions in Swift without building integrating a throw into your functions.

In other words, the following doesn't work, where myArr only has 5 items:

```
        do {
        var someItem = try myArr[10]
        }
        catch {
            print("something went wrong")
        }
```

Can anyone confirm the above simple try/catch is not possible in Swift?  In other words, one where you don't have to build some elaborate, meta exception function to handle exceptions?

Comment: This is one of the reasons Apple created Swift instead of using some other existing language. Exceptions (or more to the point, the possibility of jumping around the execution stack in weird ways) cause performance issues even in code that doesn't actually use the language feature. In the latest version of swift, they kinda-sorta added exceptions, but in a way that doesn't have the same performance baggage real exceptions would have. This is a core philosophy of the language and is unlikely to ever change.

Comment: What you see when you access an index out of bounds is an assertion, not an exception. There are no exceptions in Swift - try and catch are used for normal error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, but you have other options. You could simply check `10 < myArr.count` first.

Or, check out Erica Sadun's post on [Safe array indexing](http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/01/swift-safe-array-indexing-my-favorite-thing-of-the-new-week/):

```
// Erica Sadun / Mike Ash
// http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/01/swift-safe-array-indexing-my-favorite-thing-of-the-new-week/
extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: UInt) -> Element? {
        return Int(index) < count ? self[Int(index)] : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't specific to arrays.  That was just a good run-time example.  What you are saying is exception handling in Swift is really just if/else type stuff?  In other words, nothing built in?

Comment: Swift **errors** (`ErrorType`) are first-class citizens and work with the `try`/`throw` syntax. **Exceptions** (`assertionFailure`, `fatalError`, etc.) are considered programmer error. You may be interested in the discussion at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/258012/why-design-a-modern-language-without-an-exception-handling-mechanism

Comment: With Swift, you have to built out something elaborate to get ErrorType working.  ErrorType might be a first class citizen but error handling is total ghetto.